# Display table on button click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am building a sample project named: **Tennis Club Management** using javascript, HTML, CSS, bootstrap. In this i have a *Login Page* `(index.html)` and *Manage Players Page* `(managePlayers.html)`. In `managePlayers.html`, I have two buttons namely **Add Player** and **Show Players**. On click events of the two buttons, I need to show the tables.

**Add Players** click will show the table created in HTML and **Show Players** click will show table created in javascript as it will dynamically display table data based on the data fetched from **API**.

**The Problem** I am facing is when I click **Show Player button** the table gets displayed, and after that when I click **Add Player** button, the table does not show up.

**Below are the code files and screenshots:**

**index.html**

```
// --------------TESTING CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE LOGIN BUTTON CLICK----------------

var istableCreated = false;
var email, password,IDvalue=0;
document.querySelector(".loginbtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    email = document.querySelector(".email").value;
    password = document.querySelector(".password").value;

    document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "";
    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "";

    // ------------TESTING CODE FOR CHECKING VALIDATION AND PRINTING ERROR ON LABELS IF ANY-------------

    if (email === "admin@wimbledon.com" && password === "rogerfederer") {
        console.log("Login successfull....");
        window.open("profile.html");
    }
    else if (email === "" && password === "") {

        document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Email and Password cannot be blank"
    }
    else if (email === "") {

        document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "Email cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (password === "") {

        document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Password cannot be blank"
    }
    else {

        document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Invalid Email or Password";
    }

    console.log(email, password);
    e.preventDefault();
});





//------------------------------------MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE----------------------------------

//--------------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SHOWING PLAYERS OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE--------------------------
function showplayers() {
    document.querySelector(".customerregistration").innerHTML="";

    if (istableCreated == false) {


        istableCreated = true;
        console.log(istableCreated);

        //----------TESTING CODE FOR CREATING WRAPPER FOR BOOTSTRAP TABLE FOR RESPONSIVENESS--------

        var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
        myDiv.className = "table-responsive";
        myDiv.id = "table-responsive";
        myDiv.style.display="inline-block";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

        //-----------TESTING CODE FOR CREATING BOOTSTRAP DYNAMIC TABLE USING JAVASCRIPT-------------

        var myTable = document.createElement("table");
        myTable.style.marginTop = "2%";
        myTable.className = "table";
        myTable.id = "table";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable);


        var myThead = document.createElement("thead");
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead);

        var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr);

        var myThID = document.createElement("th");
        myThID.scope = "col";
        myThID.innerHTML = "ID";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThID);

        var myThName = document.createElement("th");
        myThName.scope = "col";
        myThName.innerHTML = "Name";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThName);

        var myThGender = document.createElement("th");

        myThGender.scope = "col";
        myThGender.innerHTML = "Gender";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThGender);

        var mySubscription = document.createElement("th");
        mySubscription.scope = "col";
        mySubscription.innerHTML = "Subscription";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(mySubscription);

        var myfeeStatus = document.createElement("th");
        myfeeStatus.scope = "col";
        myfeeStatus.innerHTML = "Fee Status";
        document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myfeeStatus);

    }
    else {
        console.log(istableCreated);
    }
}



//---------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING TABLE FOR ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION--------------- 


function addplayers() {
    console.log("add players clicked.....");
    document.querySelector(".customerregistration").style.display = "block";
    IDvalue+=1;
    // document.querySelector(".ID").value=IDvalue;

}



//--------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SAVING CUSTOMER INFORMATION OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE-----------------------------



function save() {
    console.log("data saved successfully...");
    return false;
}
```

**managePlayers.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manage Players</title>

    <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="managePlayers">

    <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW PLAYERS, ADD PLAYERS USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showplayers" onclick="showplayers();">Show Players</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addplayers" onclick="addplayers()">Add Players</button>

    <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION FORM OF CUSTOMER -->
    <table class="customerregistration">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <Label>ID :</Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class ="ID" readonly>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>DOB :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>NAME :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>GENDER :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
            </td>
            
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>CONTACT :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="customercontact" id="customercontact">
            </td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>ADDRESS :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="address" id="address" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>ID PROOF :</label>
                <select class="idproof" id="idproof">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="license">License</option>
                    <option value="aadhaar">Aadhaar</option>
                    <option value="passport">Passport</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="idprooftextbox">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>MEMBERSHIP FOR :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="membershipfor" id="membershipfor">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="court">COURT</option>
                    <option value="tournament">TOURNAMENT</option>
                    <option value="both">BOTH</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>MEMBERSHIP TYPE :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="membershiptype" id="membershiptype">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="monthly">MONTHLY</option>
                    <option value="halfyearly">HALF YEARLY</option>
                    <option value="annually">ANNUALLY</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save">SAVE</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- ADDING INDEX.JS -->
    <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: Table show on show players click]

**Nothin happens when I click on Add players**

[image: No table display]

**Any Solution please ?**

**https://jsfiddle.net/mohitsharma1991/s2ncwqvL/1/**

Comment: Js fiddle may be ?

Comment: AlwaysHelping : didn't understand ?

Comment: provide a working JS fiddle so that someone can have a look and provided you a solution.

Comment: AlwaysHelping : https://jsfiddle.net/mohitsharma1991/s2ncwqvL/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `tbody` with id selector and hide `add Player` section if the show players is clicked or vise versa when the show players is clicked you need to set the add players to `display:none`

The reason it was not working with your existing code was that you were using `innerHTML` and clearing it out completely from the `DOM` when you click `showplayers()`.

Once you were clicking it back again the `DOM` is cleared with `add player` section and does not exist anymore.

**Live Demo:**

```js
// --------------TESTING CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE LOGIN BUTTON CLICK----------------

var istableCreated = false;
var email, password, IDvalue = 0;
/* document.querySelector(".loginbtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  email = document.querySelector(".email").value;
  password = document.querySelector(".password").value;

  document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "";
  document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "";

  // ------------TESTING CODE FOR CHECKING VALIDATION AND PRINTING ERROR ON LABELS IF ANY-------------

  if (email === "admin@wimbledon.com" && password === "rogerfederer") {
    console.log("Login successfull....");
    window.open("profile.html");
  } else if (email === "" && password === "") {

    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Email and Password cannot be blank"
  } else if (email === "") {

    document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "Email cannot be blank";
  } else if (password === "") {

    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Password cannot be blank"
  } else {

    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Invalid Email or Password";
  }

  console.log(email, password);
  e.preventDefault();
});
 */


//------------------------------------MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE----------------------------------

//--------------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SHOWING PLAYERS OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE--------------------------
function showplayers() {
  // document.querySelector(".customerregistration").innerHTML = "";
  document.querySelector("#add_player").style.display = "none";

  if (istableCreated == false) {
    istableCreated = true;

    //----------TESTING CODE FOR CREATING WRAPPER FOR BOOTSTRAP TABLE FOR RESPONSIVENESS--------

    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.className = "table-responsive";
    myDiv.id = "table-responsive";
    myDiv.style.display = "inline-block";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

    //-----------TESTING CODE FOR CREATING BOOTSTRAP DYNAMIC TABLE USING JAVASCRIPT-------------

    var myTable = document.createElement("table");
    myTable.style.marginTop = "2%";
    myTable.className = "table";
    myTable.id = "table";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable);


    var myThead = document.createElement("thead");
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead);

    var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr);

    var myThID = document.createElement("th");
    myThID.scope = "col";
    myThID.innerHTML = "ID";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThID);

    var myThName = document.createElement("th");
    myThName.scope = "col";
    myThName.innerHTML = "Name";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThName);

    var myThGender = document.createElement("th");

    myThGender.scope = "col";
    myThGender.innerHTML = "Gender";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThGender);

    var mySubscription = document.createElement("th");
    mySubscription.scope = "col";
    mySubscription.innerHTML = "Subscription";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(mySubscription);

    var myfeeStatus = document.createElement("th");
    myfeeStatus.scope = "col";
    myfeeStatus.innerHTML = "Fee Status";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myfeeStatus);

  } else {
    document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "block";
  }
}



//---------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING TABLE FOR ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION--------------- 


function addplayers() {
  document.querySelector("#add_player").style.display = "block";
  if (istableCreated) {
    document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "none";
  }

  IDvalue += 1;
  // document.querySelector(".ID").value=IDvalue;
}



//--------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SAVING CUSTOMER INFORMATION OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE-----------------------------



function save() {
  console.log("data saved successfully...");
  return false;
}
```

```css
form {
  margin: auto;
  /* nice thing of auto margin if display:flex; it center both horizontal and vertical :) */
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.login {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.labelemailpassworderror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.labelemailerror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.labelpassworderror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}

.forgotpassword {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  /* margin-left: 25%; */
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

span {
  color: #1a73e8;
}

span:hover {
  color: purple;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF PROFILE PAGE---------------- */

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }

  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }

  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}

.editadminprofile {
  float: right;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE---------------- */

.showplayers {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addplayers {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE TRAINERS PAGE---------------- */

.showtrainers {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addtrainers {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE TOURNAMENTS PAGE---------------- */

.showtournaments {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addtournaments {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE MATCHES PAGE---------------- */

.showmatches {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addmatches {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE FEES PAGE---------------- */

.showfees {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addfees {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF TABLE OF MANAGE PLAYER PAGE ---------------- */

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th,
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  width: 5%;
}


/*-------------- SETING CSS PROPERTIES OF CUSTOMER REGISTRATION FORM-------------*/

.customerregistration {
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 32%;
}

#add_player {
  display: none;
}

td {
  padding: 1.4%;
}

.address {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Manage Players</title>

  <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="managePlayers">

  <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW PLAYERS, ADD PLAYERS USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showplayers" onclick="showplayers();">Show Players</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addplayers" onclick="addplayers()">Add Players</button>

  <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION FORM OF CUSTOMER -->
  <table class="customerregistration">
    <tbody id="add_player">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <Label>ID :</Label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="ID" readonly>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>DOB :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>NAME :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>GENDER :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>CONTACT :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="customercontact" id="customercontact">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ADDRESS :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="address" id="address" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ID PROOF :</label>
          <select class="idproof" id="idproof">
            <option value="select">---Select---</option>
            <option value="license">License</option>
            <option value="aadhaar">Aadhaar</option>
            <option value="passport">Passport</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idprooftextbox">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>MEMBERSHIP FOR :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="membershipfor" id="membershipfor">
            <option value="select">---Select---</option>
            <option value="court">COURT</option>
            <option value="tournament">TOURNAMENT</option>
            <option value="both">BOTH</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>MEMBERSHIP TYPE :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="membershiptype" id="membershiptype">
            <option value="select">---Select---</option>
            <option value="monthly">MONTHLY</option>
            <option value="halfyearly">HALF YEARLY</option>
            <option value="annually">ANNUALLY</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save">SAVE</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
  <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: AlwaysHelping : thank you so much brother....for your help....your solution worked for me... i was stuck on this problem since last day.....thank you once again...have a great day..... :)

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma I am happy to hear that i could help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: AlwaysHelping : there is a small issue brother that is coming up in this code i.e. when i click add player it shows the respective table for it and same is the case for show players .......BUT when i click add player button again then it shows its table but it also shows table of show players beneath it

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma I think you have do the same thing for show players table as well! just set that to display:none in your `addPlayers`

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma I have edited my answer and its working perfectly now. Please check.

Comment: AlwaysHelping : You are genius brother......it worked.....thanks a ton....have great day....once again thanks .... :)

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma No worries. Always happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `ID` of your input to another `ID`, and then your function just need to be as below.

```
function myfunction()
{
    if (document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display === "none")
        document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: AbdullahRao: thank you brother.. for your help....have a great day...thank you once again :)

Comment: No Problem Buddy

Answer (score 1):

In you `showPlayers()` method you used `document.querySelector(".customerregistration").innerHTML="";` and because of which you Add Player form has been completely removed. so, instead of using innerHTML = ''; use something like this
`document.querySelector('.customerrrgistration').style.display = "none";` and when you wanna display it use this `document.querySelector('.customerrrgistration').style.display = "block";`

Comment: keidakida : thank you brother.. for your help....have a great day...thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// --------------TESTING CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE LOGIN BUTTON CLICK----------------

var istableCreated = false;
var email, password, IDvalue = 0;
/* document.querySelector(".loginbtn").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  email = document.querySelector(".email").value;
  password = document.querySelector(".password").value;

  document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "";
  document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "";

  // ------------TESTING CODE FOR CHECKING VALIDATION AND PRINTING ERROR ON LABELS IF ANY-------------

  if (email === "admin@wimbledon.com" && password === "rogerfederer") {
    console.log("Login successfull....");
    window.open("profile.html");
  } else if (email === "" && password === "") {

    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Email and Password cannot be blank"
  } else if (email === "") {

    document.querySelector(".labelemailerror").innerHTML = "Email cannot be blank";
  } else if (password === "") {

    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Password cannot be blank"
  } else {

    document.querySelector(".labelpassworderror").innerHTML = "Invalid Email or Password";
  }

  console.log(email, password);
  e.preventDefault();
});
 */


//------------------------------------MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE----------------------------------

//--------------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SHOWING PLAYERS OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE--------------------------
function showplayers() {
  // document.querySelector(".customerregistration").innerHTML = "";
  document.querySelector("#add_player").style.display = "none";

  if (istableCreated == false) {
    istableCreated = true;

    //----------TESTING CODE FOR CREATING WRAPPER FOR BOOTSTRAP TABLE FOR RESPONSIVENESS--------

    var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
    myDiv.className = "table-responsive";
    myDiv.id = "table-responsive";
    myDiv.style.display = "inline-block";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

    //-----------TESTING CODE FOR CREATING BOOTSTRAP DYNAMIC TABLE USING JAVASCRIPT-------------

    var myTable = document.createElement("table");
    myTable.style.marginTop = "2%";
    myTable.className = "table";
    myTable.id = "table";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable);


    var myThead = document.createElement("thead");
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead);

    var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr);

    var myThID = document.createElement("th");
    myThID.scope = "col";
    myThID.innerHTML = "ID";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThID);

    var myThName = document.createElement("th");
    myThName.scope = "col";
    myThName.innerHTML = "Name";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThName);

    var myThGender = document.createElement("th");

    myThGender.scope = "col";
    myThGender.innerHTML = "Gender";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myThGender);

    var mySubscription = document.createElement("th");
    mySubscription.scope = "col";
    mySubscription.innerHTML = "Subscription";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(mySubscription);

    var myfeeStatus = document.createElement("th");
    myfeeStatus.scope = "col";
    myfeeStatus.innerHTML = "Fee Status";
    document.body.appendChild(myDiv).appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myThead).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(myfeeStatus);

  } else {
    document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "block";
  }
}



//---------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING TABLE FOR ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION--------------- 


function addplayers() {
  document.querySelector("#add_player").style.display = "block";
  if (istableCreated) {
    document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "none";
  }

  IDvalue += 1;
  // document.querySelector(".ID").value=IDvalue;
}



//--------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SAVING CUSTOMER INFORMATION OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE-----------------------------



function save() {
  console.log("data saved successfully...");
  return false;
}
```

```css
form {
  margin: auto;
  /* nice thing of auto margin if display:flex; it center both horizontal and vertical :) */
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.login {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.labelemailpassworderror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.labelemailerror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.labelpassworderror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}

.forgotpassword {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  /* margin-left: 25%; */
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

span {
  color: #1a73e8;
}

span:hover {
  color: purple;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF PROFILE PAGE---------------- */

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }

  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }

  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}

.editadminprofile {
  float: right;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE---------------- */

.showplayers {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addplayers {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE TRAINERS PAGE---------------- */

.showtrainers {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addtrainers {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE TOURNAMENTS PAGE---------------- */

.showtournaments {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addtournaments {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE MATCHES PAGE---------------- */

.showmatches {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addmatches {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE FEES PAGE---------------- */

.showfees {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addfees {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF TABLE OF MANAGE PLAYER PAGE ---------------- */

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th,
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  width: 5%;
}


/*-------------- SETING CSS PROPERTIES OF CUSTOMER REGISTRATION FORM-------------*/

.customerregistration {
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 32%;
}

#add_player {
  display: none;
}

td {
  padding: 1.4%;
}

.address {
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Manage Players</title>

  <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="managePlayers">

  <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW PLAYERS, ADD PLAYERS USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showplayers" onclick="showplayers();">Show Players</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addplayers" onclick="addplayers()">Add Players</button>

  <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION FORM OF CUSTOMER -->
  <table class="customerregistration">
    <tbody id="add_player">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <Label>ID :</Label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="ID" readonly>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>DOB :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>NAME :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="name" id="name">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>GENDER :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
          <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male
        </td>

      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>CONTACT :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="customercontact" id="customercontact">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ADDRESS :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <textarea class="address" id="address" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>ID PROOF :</label>
          <select class="idproof" id="idproof">
            <option value="select">---Select---</option>
            <option value="license">License</option>
            <option value="aadhaar">Aadhaar</option>
            <option value="passport">Passport</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="idprooftextbox">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>MEMBERSHIP FOR :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="membershipfor" id="membershipfor">
            <option value="select">---Select---</option>
            <option value="court">COURT</option>
            <option value="tournament">TOURNAMENT</option>
            <option value="both">BOTH</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>MEMBERSHIP TYPE :</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="membershiptype" id="membershiptype">
            <option value="select">---Select---</option>
            <option value="monthly">MONTHLY</option>
            <option value="halfyearly">HALF YEARLY</option>
            <option value="annually">ANNUALLY</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save">SAVE</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
  <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.